# Is the correct way to approach converting Groovy Closures to a form that RxJava can use

Tags: groovy, closures, rx-java

I have just started to look at using RxJava V3 with Groovy v3.  Naturally my inclination is to start with Closures.

But RxJava subscribe () method doesn't accept them.  So I have implemented a FunctionalClosure concrete class that acts as the conversion from closure to Rxjava  Consumer, or Function or MethodClosure like this below.

What I'm not sure of is, is this idiomatically the 'best' Groovy way to address my problem.  Part of the problem is that the Groovy Closure is an abstract class so you have to extend it.  Secondly the only way I could find to 'store' the submitted closure was to have a Closure reference inside this concrete implementation.

What I cannot understand is when you write `Closure myClos = {xx ->  ...}` in the editor to create a closure, where is this executable code stored ?  Implicitly I'd want to store my clone of the input closure into the same place - but looking at the code for the abstract Closure class I can't actually figure out where this is.

You are supposed to implement a `doCall ()` method on your concrete class, which I have done, and this just invoked the internal action closure variable

```
import groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure

/**
 * class to wrap a closure and convert it into a RxJava Consumer
 * @param <T>  expected type of the arg that that the closure will be called with
 */
@InheritConstructors
class FunctionalClosure<T, R> extends Closure implements Consumer<T>, Function<T,R> {

    private Closure action = {}

    //maximumNumberOfParameters = 1
    //parameterTypes = EMPTY_CLASS_ARRAY

    FunctionalClosure() {
        super(null)
    }

    FunctionalClosure (final Closure clos) {
        //setup the abstract closure with the owner of the closure
        //super(clos?.owner)
        super (clos.clone())

        maximumNumberOfParameters = clos.getMaximumNumberOfParameters()
        action = clos.clone()
   }

    //implement doCall to direct the call() to the action closure
    protected Object doCall(Object arguments) {
        return action(arguments)
    }

    Closure<T> leftShift (final Closure clos) {
        action = clos.clone()

    }

    /**
     * as we have an embedded action closure, make sure when setting the closure delegate
     * that this is set on the action.
     * @param delegate - the object you want to provide the context for the action
     */
    //
    void setDelegate (Object delegate) {
        action.delegate = delegate
    }

    /**
     * implements the RxJava Consumer contract, takes a generic arg of type T,
     * an invokes the closure call () with the arg
     * @param arg
     */
    void accept (T arg) {
        call (arg)
    }

    /**
     * implements the RxJava Function contract, takes a generic arg of type T,
     * an invokes the closure call () with the arg, and returns the result of the call
     * @param arg
     */
    R apply (T arg) {
        return call (arg)
    }


        /**
     * static from method, accepts a closure and assigns a clone of it
     * and returns result as Consumer<T>
     * @param clos pass some closure to convert to Functional type
     * @return Consumer<T>
     */
    static <T> Consumer<T>  consumerFrom (Closure clos ) {
        assert clos

        if (clos.maximumNumberOfParameters == 0){
            throw new IncorrectClosureArgumentsException("from: closure must accept at least one argument")
        }
        Closure cons = new FunctionalClosure<>(clos.clone())
        cons
    }

    /**
     * static from method, accepts a closure and assigns a clone of it
     * and returns result as Function<T, R>
     * @param clos pass some closure to convert to Functional type
     * @return Consumer<T>
     */
    static <T,R> Function<T, R>  functionFrom (Closure clos ) {
        assert clos

        if (clos.maximumNumberOfParameters == 0){
            throw new IncorrectClosureArgumentsException("from: closure must accept at least one argument")
        }
        Closure cons = new FunctionalClosure<>(clos.clone())
        cons
    }

    /**
     * static from method, accepts a closure and assigns a clone of it
     * and returns result as Consumer<T>
     * @param clos pass some closure to convert to Functional type
     * @return Consumer<T>
     */

    static MethodClosure asMethodClosure (Closure clos ) {
        assert clos

        Closure cons = new FunctionalClosure<>(clos.clone())
        cons::accept
    }

}
```

This all seems to work, that is I can write a script like this, and it will print all the numbers when I subscribe with either a consumer, or whether I use the static `FunctionalClosure.asMethodClosure {println it}` method.

```
Consumer cons = new FunctionalClosure ()
cons << {println it}

Flowable pl = Flowable.fromIterable([1,2,3])

//Function pc = {num -> println num} as Function

pl.map{num -> num*2}.subscribe(cons)
```

What I'm hoping for is that some one can say 'this is the correct' way to address this or whether in fact that that there is better more idiomatic Groovy way to do this.

Comment: Groovy will usually "cast" closures to single method interfaces. This fails when it can not decide what to do when there are multiple different arguments to a function. So I assume that `subscribe` takes multiple and `.subscribe({ ... } as Function)` should do.

Answer (score 3):

Let us first take a working example of code without FunctionalClosure:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='io.reactivex.rxjava3', module='rxjava', version='3.0.0')
)
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.*
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.*

Flowable pl = Flowable.fromIterable([1,2,3])
pl.map {num -> num*2}.subscribe {num -> println num}
```

This was using Groovy 3.0.1 and it is perfectly fine accepting the Closure argument for the subscribe method. I would also call this the idiomatic way.

If it is really the shift you want to keep:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='io.reactivex.rxjava3', module='rxjava', version='3.0.0')
)
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.*
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.*

def mul2 = {num -> num*2}
def add1 = {num -> num+1}
def add1AndDouble = add1>>mul2

Flowable pl = Flowable.fromIterable([1,2,3])
pl.map (add1AndDouble).subscribe {it -> println it}
```

or use `mul2<<add1` if it has to be a left shift.

As of "where is this executable code stored ?" The main answer is that Groovy will create an inner class which extends Closure. This inner class of your current class or script (Closure will not be changed of course) will have a doCall method, which will be called if you call the "call" method on Closure. If you are using a "MethodClosure", then the code is stored in the method you reference and the Closure is only a caller front-end for the method call. In Groovy 3 more and more code will use the java 8+ way of implementing this and produce an invokedynamic call. Then the code is stored in a method of the current class/script.

If you write code in Groovy you normally do not have to extend Closure at all. Only if you want to call something in Groovy, that takes a Closure and your calling code is not Groovy, then you may want to do that.